# Primefaces: required field message overrides <p:dialog/> message

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces, validation

I have a field that has a required attribute. When I press the **Accept** button to save some data without entering any value in the field, an error message is displayed. So far so good. 
But, if right after that I decide to click on the **Cancel** button, that error message overrides the confirmation message that is supposed to be displayed inside a `<p:dialog/>` element.

**NOTE:** If instead I use the `<p:confirmDialog/>` component, there seems to be no problem because, I guess, it uses a `message=""` attribute, no the `<p:messages/>` tag.

**XHTML**

```
<p:dialog>
<p:outputPanel>
      <h:form>

      <h:outputText value="Field:"/>
      <p:inputText id="field" value="" type="text" required="true" requiredMessage="You must complete the field" />                         
      <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

      <p:commandButton id="dialogCancel" value="Cancel" oncomplete="confirmCancelDialog.show();"  actionListener="#{controller.addCloseWarn}" />    

      </h:form>
</p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>

<h:form>
<p:dialog id="confirmCancelDialog" header="Warning!" widgetVar="confirmCancelDialog" modal="true" >                                         
    <p:messages id="closeMessage" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />                                    
    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Accept" onclick="..." />  
    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Cancel" onclick="..." />               
</p:dialog> 
</h:form>
```

**Bean controller**

```
public void addCloseWarn(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("closeMessage", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, null, 
                          "Are you sure you want to leave the page?")); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post structure of xhtml page with position of form inside which are input field and button? Is this form with dialog potentially inside another form?

Comment: @partlov Sure. There I edited the post. The form with dialog is separated from the form that contains the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with Cancel button is that your form is submitted and validation is executed. You can add `process="@this"` attribute to `commandButton`, so other parts of form will not be processed and your `addCloseWarn` method will be executed.

I would also add that this is probably not standard use of `message` tag. It is used to show errors, warning and successful messages, not confirmation questions. So use `confirmDialog` or use standard dialog with just ordinary text and OK - Cancel buttons.